# How to make this gradient drop shadow?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, interface-design, iphone

I have messed around with a few options, but have not come up with a good solution to recreate this gradient drop shadow effect.

[image: Original Toolbar]

[image: Close up on Drop Shadow]

Comment: this may help you: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18034/how-do-i-create-a-button-with-two-shadows-in-the-bottom/18037#18037

Comment: possible duplicate of [Photoshop curved Shadow](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1441/photoshop-curved-shadow)

Comment: Ideally, you'd render it in code (CSS if a web app)

Answer (score 3):

I imagine one of the reasons why you are having difficulty with this shadow is because it kind of gets smaller in the center, it doesn't go all the way to the ends.

I would re-create it using a new element:

- Create a white rectangle (your page) over a gray background

[image]

- In a nee layer under the rectangle, draw a black oval shape the size of your desired shadow

[image]

- Select the oval, go to `Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur` and blur your shape until it looks like the shadow. Because it's under the white rectangle, you should only see the bottom part.

[image]

You can also add a little drop-shadow to the white paper, minimal.

Comment: These are both good options but it seems to almost be a masked gradient on the drop shadow? I'll see if I can make this gaussian blur work in the mean time.

Comment: Yes, that's another good option!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a blur tilt-shift effect on your preexisting drop shadow.

> - Create a drop shadow at 90 degrees, 1 px distance, 100% opacity, Size 1
> - Right click the "fx" and select create Layer, press OK
> - Select newly created layer and navigate to `Filter > Blur Gallery > Tilt-shift`
> - Using 1 or 2 points you can turn and maneuver the focus point to create the illusion of the desired drop shadow.

Once that is finished you can then clean up the shadow as desired.

[image: End Result without Cleanup]